# Firestore: query with array comparison

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to achieve things similar to `ref.whereField("userID", existsIn: friendArray)`, which would allow me to filter out friends from a collection of users. I know such query is not supported. A client side solution such as `db.collection("users").getDocuments() { //iterate documents }` might not be very data friendly, is there a server side solution?

Comment: structure ("architect") your firestore data first aiming for best performance and scalability, then build out your code/queries.

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't show your document structure, I suppose you currently have something like:

```
{
  "user_name": "Jon Doe",
  "friendArray": [{
    0: "userID",
    1: "userID2",
    2: "userID3"
  }]
}
```

But the [Firestore Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays) recommend structuring your data as:

```
{
  "name": "Jon Doe",
  "friendArray": {
    "userID": true,
    "userID2": true,
    "userID3": true
  }
}
```

This way, you can retrieve all users who have `userID` in their list of friends using:

```
db.collection("users")
    .whereField("friendArray.userID", isEqualTo: true)
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in

        // ...

}
```